# Как составить регулярное выражение "найти все до ПЕРВОГО знака, игнорируя остальные"?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, excel, libre-office

К примеру, вот текст: `Яблоко|апельсин|груша|вишня`

Необходимо найти всё до ПЕРВОГО символа `|`, то есть наш текст в итоге должен выглядеть так: `апельсин|груша|вишня`.

Как это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения? В том же Excel, например.

Comment: Судя по всему, вы имеете ввиду как удалить из строки текст до первого вхождения |, да?

Comment: @Joker Да, верно.

Comment: Можно использовать такое выражение `^.+?\|(.+$)` для функции replace где прежнюю строку заменить найденной группой.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в файле огромное множество разнообразных значений в большом столбце.То есть там у меня не только яблоки и апельсины, как в примере. Но суть одна – надо удалить всё до самого первого знака | 
С выражением ^.+?\|(.+$) идёт просто чистое удаление. А заменять, естественно, не на что, т.к. значения везде разные.

Comment: А вы использовали подстановку `$1` (в зависимости от среды может различаться)?

Comment: Формулой: `=ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("|";A2)+1;999)`

Comment: В итоге подошло выражение ^[^|]*
Всем спасибо за советы.)